android.media.ImageReader with MediaProjection stucks on Android 14
I am using MediaProjection for screen sharing with WebRTC. After updating my Pixel 7 Pro to Android 14, it no longer captures frames properly. On older Android versions, it worked without any issues.
Behavior:
Screen capture starts, and I receive a few frames (40-50), but then no new frames are captured. There are no errors or "stop" callbacks; the onImageAvailableListener callback simply stops being called.
Expected behaviour:
When screen content changes new frames are consistently captured
To investigate further, I created an empty project with the bare minimum code needed to start screen capture. The code is below.
I discovered that this issue seems to be related to ImageReader. When attaching SurfaceView to VirtualDisplay, frames are delivered consistently.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue with MediaProjection on Android 14? Is there a known workaround or solution for this problem?
class MediaProjectionCapturer(private val mediaProjectionData: Intent) {

    private var imageCounter = 0

    private val imageReaderMaxImages = 2

    private lateinit var virtualDisplay: VirtualDisplay

    private val listenerHandler : Handler

    init {
        val listenerHandlerThread = HandlerThread(TAG)
        listenerHandlerThread.start()
        listenerHandler = Handler(listenerHandlerThread.looper)
    }

    fun start(context: Context, displaySurface: Surface?) { // ❗❗❗ <- passing surfaceView.holder.surface if not null
        val screenConfig = loadScreenConfig(context)
        val surface = if (displaySurface != null) {
            displaySurface // <- ❗❗❗ surfaceView.holder.surface
        }  else {
            val reader = ImageReader.newInstance(
                screenConfig.width,
                screenConfig.height,
                PixelFormat.RGBA_8888,
                imageReaderMaxImages
            )
            val imageAvailableListener = onImageAvailableListener()
            reader.setOnImageAvailableListener(imageAvailableListener, listenerHandler)
            reader.surface // <- ❗❗❗imageReader surface
        }

        val display = createVirtualDisplay(
            context = context,
            screenConfig = screenConfig,
            displaySurface = surface // <- ❗❗❗ Setting the surface to VirtualDisplay
        )

        virtualDisplay = display
    }

    private fun onImageAvailableListener () = ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener { imageReader ->
        Log.d("ImageAvailable", "Delivered new image $imageCounter")
        imageReader.acquireNextImage()?.close()
        ++imageCounter
    }

    private fun createVirtualDisplay(
        context: Context,
        screenConfig: ScreenConfig,
        displaySurface: Surface
    ): VirtualDisplay {
        val projectionManager = context.getSystemService(
            Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE
        ) as MediaProjectionManager

        val projection = projectionManager.getMediaProjection(RESULT_OK, mediaProjectionData)

        projection.registerCallback(
            object : MediaProjection.Callback() {
                override fun onStop() {
                    onStop()
                }
            }, listenerHandler
        )

        return projection.createVirtualDisplay(
            TAG,
            screenConfig.width,
            screenConfig.height,
            screenConfig.dpi,
            DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR,
            displaySurface,
            null,
            null
        )
    }

    private fun loadScreenConfig(context: Context): ScreenConfig {
        val metrics: DisplayMetrics
        val width: Int
        val height: Int
        val dpi: Int

        val windowManager = context.getSystemService(WindowManager::class.java)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            val windowMetrics = windowManager.currentWindowMetrics
            width = windowMetrics.bounds.width()
            height = windowMetrics.bounds.height()
            dpi = context.resources.displayMetrics.densityDpi
        } else {
            metrics = DisplayMetrics()
            @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
            windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(metrics)
            width = metrics.widthPixels
            height = metrics.heightPixels
            dpi = metrics.densityDpi
        }

        return ScreenConfig(width, height, dpi)
    }

    private data class ScreenConfig(val width: Int, val height: Int, val dpi: Int)
}

